# Tag files and archives for easy easy access and search in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, file-management, tags

Is there a tool that lets you tag things, so that you can find or organize stuff easily?

I have a bunch of folders containing zip and rar files. Most of the zip and rar files contain photos. Is there a software in Windows 7 that lets you organize those folders and tag them, so when you're looking for a specific file it can be searched or be found in tags?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[tag2find](http://www.tag2find.com/about.0.html) sounds interesting. I haven't tried it, but it seems like a good, popular solution. Should run fine on Windows 7.

[image: screenshot]

And here's how to search for files by tag:

[image]

Comment: this is the tool i've been looking for! Thanks for sharing!

Comment: You're very welcome. Let us know how it works out with Win7 :)

Comment: It doesn't work on Windows 7 x64.  Too bad, that looks like a cool tool.