# Tagging files/folders for MacOS X AND Windows?

Tags: windows-7, macos, windows-xp, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [tag based file organizer](https://superuser.com/questions/252537/tag-based-file-organizer)

I'm searching for a tool which allows me to add **tags** to files in `MacOS X (10.6.8)` and in  `Windows XP` (or `Win 7`).

The tags shall be

- readable for both systems, when e. g. opening a directory on the Windows PC  by file sharing over the local network from MacOS X or vice versa
- and they shall stick to the file, so that they get copied with the file e. g. when moving it to a USB flash drive or sending it via e-mail.

(Up to now I've been using `DevonThink Pro Office` on MacOS X which uses OpenMeta tags for file tagging. I assume that those tags can not be read or edited in Windows?!)

Comment: To achieve this in OS X you'd probably use [resource forks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_fork). 

This would result in `._` files being copied to non-Apple filesystems such as FAT32 or NTFS, since they cannot handle resource forks and need an extra file for the information to be carried along. 

If you have to have the tags sticking to the file, there's no way around that, I'm afraid.

Comment: possible duplicate of [tag based file organizer](http://superuser.com/questions/252537/tag-based-file-organizer) also see [Tag files and archives for easy easy access and search in Windows 7](http://superuser.com/questions/57309/tag-files-and-archives-for-easy-easy-access-and-search-in-windows-7?rq=1) and [What's good tagging software for Windows Explorer?](http://superuser.com/questions/109099/whats-good-tagging-software-for-windows-explorer)

Comment: @techie007: IMHO this is not a duplicate, as none of the others questions is about platform-independent tagging systems